# How do I prove that the following function of a standard normal random variable is again standard normal distributed?

Tags: probability

I am stuck with the following exercise.

> Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. Show that for each $a>0$, the random variable
> $$Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} X & \mbox{if } |X|\leq a \\
> -X & \mbox{if } |X|>a \end{array}\right.
> $$
> is again standard normal.

I am told to use characteristic functions and given the hint to write $Y=h(X)$. This is $h(X)=\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq a\}}X-\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>a\}}X$ I believe. I have produced a sketch of this function on the XY-plane but am stuck at this step. I would appreciate a hint on how to show that $\varphi_X(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX})=\mathbb{E}(e^{ith(X)})=\varphi_Y(t)$.

Comment: Your $h(X)$ can only take the values $\pm1$.  Using $Y=X\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq a\}}-\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>a\}}\right)$ might work

Comment: That is what I had in mind – thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try definition?
$$
\begin{align*}
P(Y \leq t) &= P(Y \leq t, |X| \leq a) + P(Y \leq t, |X| > a)\\
&= P(X \leq t, |X| \leq a) +P(X \geq -t, |X| > a),
\end{align*}
$$
and since $X$ is symmetric and continuous, the last bit equals $P(X \leq t).$ (A *symmetric* random variable is a random variable such that $P(X \in R) = P(-X \in R)$ for all $R$ Borel sets.)

**Characteristic function approach.** Consider $Y = X \left( \mathbf{1}_{ \{|X| \leq a\} } - \mathbf{1}_{\{|X|>a\}} \right).$ Then
$$
E(e^{itY}) = \int\limits_{|x| \leq a} e^{itx} f_X(x) dx + \int\limits_{|x| > a} e^{it(-x)} f_X(x) dx, 
$$
and use the change of variable $u = -x$ in the second integral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am asked specifically to use characteristic functions in my solution.

Comment: Okay, I thought you were _suggested_ to use ch. fun.

Comment: Dear @William M., thanks for your amended answer. Proceeding from where you left off, I get for the second integral $-\int_{|u|>a}e^{itu}f_X(-u)du=-\int_{|u|>a}e^{itu}f_X(u)du$ using the fact that the density function is even. Am I on the right path? I suspect I made a mistake in the change of variables. Sorry if this is evident!

Comment: Under the transformation $u = -x,$ the set $|x|>a$ maps to $|u|>a.$

Comment: If you want to do it "calculus" style, you will need to split the integral into $x < -a$ and $x > a,$ then these transform correspondingly to $u > a$ and $u < -a,$ but the "limits of integration" will be flipped and a negative sign will appear in front of the integral, then you use the definition $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a.$

Comment: This is helpful, thanks!